# Is there a way to test ios application developed using react native in windows OS?

Tags: react-native-windows

I have a Windows 10 PC and Visual studio 2015 installed.
I want to develop an iOS app using react native framework. 
And I want to run the iOS app and test it in the same Windows 10 PC.
Is that possible?
If Yes, please let me know the steps and process to follow.
If No, what is the best suggested way?

Comment: Hi you can use MAC VM on your windows PC. Other than that I think there is no such a way to run or test iOS app on a Windows PC. You can find more than hundred of examples/guides if you just google “how to use MAC VM on Windows 10 PC”

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am in a process of getting a MAC OS VM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi you can use Virtual machine with macOS image.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shreyas. I am in a process of getting a MAC OS VM.